# itemClicked event selector objective c

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode6

I am extremely new to ObjC and am trying to build my first app. However I seem to have hit a barrier. I am building a menubar app and I want to create an alert when the item is clicked, to say that the click is acknowledged.

This is what I have written in the .h file, but I get an error asking me to end the statement after the (id)sender with a ;.

```
- (void)itemClicked:(id)sender {
    NSAlert * alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Toggle Acknowledge"
                                      defaultButton:@"Gotcha!"
                                    alternateButton:nil
                                        otherButton:nil
                          informativeTextWithFormat:@"NSStatusItem was clicked"]
    [alert runModal] }
```

Not sure what am doing here! Any help would be fantastic, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do what the error asks, in Objective-C all lines must end with a semicolon

```
- (void)itemClicked:(id)sender {
    NSAlert * alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Toggle Acknowledge"
                                      defaultButton:@"Gotcha!"
                                    alternateButton:nil
                                        otherButton:nil
                          informativeTextWithFormat:@"NSStatusItem was clicked", nil];
    [alert runModal];
}
```

I added a `nil` statement as the format parameter to avoid a warning.

**Edit:**

In Yosemite (and higher) it's recommended to use this

```
- (void)itemClicked:(id)sender {
    NSAlert * alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
    alert.messageText = @"Toggle Acknowledge";
    alert.informativeText = @"NSStatusItem was clicked";
    [alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Gotcha!"];
    [alert runModal];
}
```

Comment: I had tried using the ; copying your code seems to fix it 0.o. Thank you anyways :)

Comment: you replace nsalert to uilaertview

Comment: We're talking about OS X

Comment: @Vadian: Gives me a warning for NSAlert, OS X (10.3 and later)Deprecated:Instead, alloc and init an NSAlert object and set its attributes as appropriate. Thought you might want to know :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)itemClicked:(id)sender
{
     NSAlert * alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:
                                      defaultButton:@"Gotcha!"
                                    alternateButton:nil
                                        otherButton:nil
                          informativeTextWithFormat:@"NSStatusItem was clicked", nil];
    [alert beginSheetModalForWindow:window modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:@selector(alertDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo:nil];
}
```

Just use and check then give me feedback

Comment: As vadian said, UIAlertView is not defined in cocoa, I think